# alternative to HermesJMS tool for WebSphere MQ

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I have been facing issues in pasting an XML message to a IBM WebSphere MQ queue via HermesJMS. During my search, I had also thought of finding out an alternative if any, which could help me out in accomplishing my task.

However, I did NOT find any alternative for HermesJMS. I had found out OpenJMS, but that is an implementation of JMS (similar to ApacheMQ, RabbitMQ, IBM WebSphere MQ etc.,).

Have any of you used any other (easy to use, open source) tools (clients) for browsing MQ queues and messages, which can stand as an alternative to HermesJMS?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Websphere, have you tried [MQ Explorer](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/explorer/)? This is also open-source.

If you are trying to do performance testing, I would give [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) a go.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. However I was told (and also under an impression that) MQExplorer is a commercial tool. Hence, had NOT tried yet. Will check it out and let you know. All I need is just to have a tool to browse and post messages to the Queue.

Comment: In that case you should have a look at SupportPac MS0T (WMQ Explorer) and SupportPac MO71 (MQMon).  Both of these are free tools to browse and put/get messages on queues and topics.  WMQ Explorer is the tool that is fully supported and considered part of the WMQ distribution.  MO71 is another favorite but is delivered free and as-is.  See http://ibm.co/SupptPacs to download these and any of the other SupportPacs.